# How are interfaces used and work in the Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

There is a [directory](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/v23.0/src/interfaces) called interfaces. I've seen usage of interface classes in other places but never understood how do they work because they're trivially just an interface and therefore do nothing by their own. Can someone explain the mechanism they work in the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interfaces classes just provide API definitions.

For example the `interface::Wallet` class declares a virtual `interfaces::Wallet::getWalletTxs()` method that GUI code can call to list wallet transactions. Wallet code provides a `wallet::WalletImpl` class that inherits from `interfaces::Wallet` and provides a `wallet::WalletImpl::getWalletTxs()` implementation of that method.

Because of the interface definition, GUI code can call the wallet code through the interface without being linked to wallet code or even necessarily running in the same process.

Answer (score 0):

I think these interfaces are <s>exclusively</s> used in the running of Bitcoin Core in multiprocess mode ([1](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/design/multiprocess.md), [2](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/98398/what-is-the-motivation-behind-russell-yanofskys-work-to-separate-bitcoin-core-i/)). When running Bitcoin Core as a single process (which is the default mode) these interfaces aren't used. However, multi processes need a way for a process to communicate with another process and this is done through these well defined interfaces.

Comment: That's not correct. They're used right now already for interaction between various components (though the goal of this is having a unified interface between components, so that later those components may end up running in different processes).

Comment: Ok I'll wait for your answer on this then. Feel free to downvote this :)